# Appending objects to a list and keeping the index intact even when certain iterations are excluded

Tags: python, django

I'm appending objects to a python list via the following simple code:

```
 for index, link in enumerate(context["object_list"]):
            if link.publicreply_set.exists():
                latest_reply = link.publicreply_set.latest('submitted_on')
                if latest_reply in link.publicreply_set.filter(publicreply_seen_related__seen_user = user ,publicreply_seen_related__which_reply = latest_reply):
                    eachlink[index].append(link)
                    eachlink[index].append(latest_reply.submitted_on)
                    eachlink[index].append(None)
                else:
                    eachlink[index].append(None)
                    eachlink[index].append(latest_reply.submitted_on)
                    eachlink[index].append(link)
            else:
                eachlink[index].append(link)
                eachlink[index].append(None)
                eachlink[index].append(None)
```

I've been trying to change this code such that the loop doesn't append anything in the *outer* else (e.g. `pass`). But problem with this approach is that the *index value gets skipped too*.

What's an elegant way to do this differently in a way that avoids index value getting skipped?

Comment: how is eachlink related to context?

Comment: I'm confused; are you saying that if *exists* comes up false, then you do *not* want to increment index?  I'm not sure what you *do* want to happen in the outer else case.

Comment: Hey ergonaut! `link` is actually a posted url people share on my website. So `object_list` is made up of `links`. With `eachlink`, I'm making a new list that contains some extra information around each `link` object (hence called eachlink).

Comment: Prune, here's my problem. If we're at `index = n`, and `exists()` is false, the list at `nth` index would be empty, no? I pass this context to a django template, where I go through the key value pairs and print everything out serially. I'll get empty indices printed on my template in that case, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually control index as follows:

```
index = 0
for link in context["object_list"]:
    if link.publicreply_set.exists():
        ...
        index += 1
```

You can omit the final `else`.  The point is you manually increment index only when you want to.

Comment: Yea something like this essentially, but I'm thinking, would this be pythonic?

Comment: Anyhoo, without further ado, I'm settling with this.